# rails plugin isn't installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to install restful_authentication plugin use following git...

```
git://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication.git
```

and i am trying to install using following command...

c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\rails_apps\students>`ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication.git`

But its not installing as expected, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but what version of rails are you using? The restful authentication plugin hasn't been updated in a long while, as you can see on the github project: https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication. Unless you're on Rails 2.3.x, i'd recommend looking at: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: ruby -v tells `ruby 1.9.2p290`

Comment: what does rails -v output? That's your ruby version :).

Comment: Ah okay. Is there a particular issue that you are running into? Are you getting an error & stack trace? It's been a long time since I've used that plugin. My recommendation is to double check you followed the "After installation" steps correctly listed in the readme file on the repository. On another note, if you're relatively new to rails, I suggest looking at using Rails 3 if you can. It definitely has better ruby 1.9 support than 2.0.2. I think 2.3 has the best ruby 1.9 support as far as 2.x goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user on **terminal**:

```
[sudo] gem install restful-authentication
```

or

```
[sudo] rails plugin install git://github.com/Satish/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
```

and insert on **Gemfile**:

```
[sudo] gem "restful-authentication", "~> 1.2.1"
```

or

```
[sudo] gem "restful-authentication"
```

- ***if you'r on linux or mac, you can user sudo.***